# Javascript Post method in Razor Pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm studying javascript methods but I have difficult to make POST method works.
Below you can see the code that I use to test:

```
<form id="form_test">
    <h5>POST Method</h5>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text_input">
    <button type="button" onclick="Save()">Send</button>
</form>
```

```
function Save() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "/Page1?handler=Save";
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);

  let data = `{
        "Id": 78912,
        "Customer": "Jason Sweet",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Price": 18.00
      }`;

  xhr.send(data);
}
```

```
public IActionResult OnPostSave()
        {
            return new JsonResult("my result");
        }
```

Any idea what can do wrong?

Comment: create a post action method that has [HttpPost] attribute. -  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/httpget-and-httppost-attributes-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I added the above but I get a message saying that HttpPostAttribute cant be applied to Razor Pages handler methods. Any clue?

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix the URL where you want to send the post request. Also need to use **[HttpPost]** attribute for the action method.

Below is link to an example which uses XMLHttpRequest to POST data to method

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-AJAX-Call-using-XML-using-XmlHttpRequest-XHR-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work on Razor pages, as the first comment says